# error: cannot find symbol - maven install com class folder

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, pom

Tenho um projecto maven no eclipse que usa um class folder. Essa pasta tem os .java e os .class. As classes que uso no projecto estão no build path como class folder, quando faço maven install dá me erro:

```
[ERROR] location: class PushJobProcessor
[ERROR] xxx\java\com\xxx\Processor.java:[152,11] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Já tentei mudei da versão de java, mas nada...
Conseguem dar uma ideia do que seja ?

Obrigado pela atenção

Comment: Qual a estrutura que se encontra o teu source folder? Tive problemas a algum tempo pois o Maven só reconhecia a estrutura padrão via linha de comando **src/main/java**, diferente disso é necessário configurações adicionais no **pom.xml**

Comment: Como está o seu pom.xml? Coloque-o na pergunta por favor.

Comment: Eu separeu o meu código de test do projeto e coloquei ele em outro projeto, depois disso o erro desapareceu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta alterar a versão do plugin do Maven para a 3.1

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```